# Jenkins can't launch selenium tests (Timed out waiting for profile to be created)

Tags: java, ubuntu, continuous-integration, selenium-rc, jenkins

Jenkins can't launch selenium tests (ubuntu)
error

*11:26:24.652 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@ab50cd
11:26:24.738 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
HTML suite exception seen:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out waiting for profile to be created!
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.waitForFullProfileToBeCreated(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:360)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.populateCustomProfileDirectory(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.launch(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.launchHTMLSuite(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:405)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxLauncher.launchHTMLSuite(FirefoxLauncher.java:105)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.runHTMLSuite(HTMLLauncher.java:121)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.runHTMLSuite(HTMLLauncher.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.runHtmlSuite(SeleniumServer.java:556)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.boot(SeleniumServer.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.main(SeleniumServer.java:201)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher.main(GridLauncher.java:40)*

OS - Ubuntu workstation 11
Jenkins & Selenium - last versions (installed as is it written on sites)

It seems to me that user jenkins have not all the rights, because if i use the same line to execute in terminal, it works selenium starts Firefox & do the suite.

I also put jenkins user in groop root but it also doesn't help.

I'm not qualified in Linux but it seems than trouble is with rights of jenkins user, but i can mistake.

If somebody have solved the problem please write the solution.

Comment: started jenkins as a root - the same.

Answer (score 8):

I was recently having this issue too.

I first tried the method mentioned here : http://www.spacevatican.org/2008/9/27/selenium-and-firefox-3 However this fix now seems out of date, as the plugin maxVersion properties were all set to 8.something.

The way I fixed it (as mentioned here : http://www.centripetal.ca/blog/2011/02/07/getting-started-with-selenium-and-jenkins/) was to provide Selenium with a firefox profile.

Steps

1. Open up Firefox profile manager : $ firefox -ProfileManager
2. Create a new profile, called Selenium
3. Now, when running the selenium command, add "-firefoxProfileTemplate "/home/{username}/.mozilla/firefox/{profile dir}" to the command. (where {username} is your username and {profile dir} is the profile directory, which for me was "6f2um01h.Selenium"

My final Selenium command was

```
$ sudo java -jar /var/lib/jenkins/tools/selenium/selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite *firefox http://google.com "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Selenium setup test/workspace/tests/test-testsuite.html" "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Selenium setup test/workspace/results/results.html" -log=/tmp/selenium.log -debug=true -firefoxProfileTemplate "/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/6f2um01h.Selenium"
```

---

I would also recommend copying and pasting the shell command that jenkins is using into Terminal, to save having to run it through Jenkins each time.

---

N.B. I'm currently finding that Selenium now hangs (and doesn't crash) on the next step of it's process (Launching Firefox) but this seems like a different bug which I've added to stackoverflow here : [Selenium hangs when launching Firefox on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154836/selenium-hangs-when-launching-firefox-on-ubuntu)

Comment: If the command will run from the command line, but not from within Jenkins, it's likely to be a permissions issue. Does the jenkins user have the permissions to run Firefox/access the profile directory?

Comment: i made profile for FF
in Jenkins
settings are as follows
http://clip2net.com/s/17Zms
error in Jenkins
http://clip2net.com/s/17Zoh

Comment: I guess it depends on your setup, but it seems like the path to the profile is incorrect. The path needs to be to the directory where Firefox stores the profile data. For me, that's within the user folder that Firefox is run with - ~/.mozilla/firefox.

Within that folder, there's likely to be a couple of profiles. Open up profiles.ini to see which folder is referenced by the profile you've created for jenkins. The full path (without the user shortcut ~/) to this folder is what needs to follow the selenium -firefoxProfileTemplate part of the command.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issues. But the cause and solution are different.

The program (I use python) hangs for a while, and then output:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser
>   appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: ***
>   LOG addons.xpi: startup\n*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges\n*** LOG
>   addons.xpi: Opening database\n*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes
>   found\nFailed to dlopen /usr/lib/libX11.so.6\ndlerror says:
>   /usr/lib/libX11.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32\n'

It is because I have installed both 32 and 64 bit version of libX11. By removing libX11 32 bit version, the program works.

Answer (score 0):

@mattbilson's solution didn't work for me, but I found a different solution to a problem with the same symtomps. I believe In the process of trying to debug the problem, multiple versions of Firefox had been installed, and not all from clean deb packages.

To fix the problem I did:

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox
sudo mv /usr/lib/firefox /usr/lib/firefox.bak
sudo apt-get install firefox=<MY_FIREFOX_VERSION>
```

After that I could run the Selenium JAR without any special parameters.