# Executing Selenium HTML Test Suite in Jenkins is not able to launch on firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium, jenkins, test-suite

I am trying to integrate Jenkins with Selenium. I have prepared the following command:

```
java -jar <Full Path of the Selenium RC Jar, including jar file name> \
 -htmlSuite *firefox "<Application URL>" \
 "<Test Suite Path Including test suite name>" "<Results file name>"
```

When I executed the command in the command line, it worked fine. Then I called the same command through Jenkins and I got the following error:

```
INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
HTML suite exception seen:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out waiting for profile to be created!
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.waitForFullProfileToBeCreated(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:360)
    at
```

Then we created a profile for Firefox and ran with the profile. Now I am getting the following error:

```
516 [main] INFO org.openqa.jetty.util.Container - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@13f3045
HTML suite exception seen:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.io.FileHandler.copyDir(FileHandler.java:229)
    at org.openqa.selenium.io.FileHandler.copy(FileHandler.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.io.FileHandler.copy(FileHandler.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.LauncherUtils.copyDirectory(LauncherUtils.java:223)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.copyDirectory(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:147)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.initProfileTemplate(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.makeCustomProfile(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:221)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.launch(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:89)
    at
```

I have jenkins 1.452 and seleniumHQ2.0

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: Under which user is running jenkins? Is it running as root?

Comment: What's your OS? Windows? or Linux?

Answer (score 4):

Before I invoke, Selenium RC, I have added one more command to export display, with this I am able to run selenium RC from Jenkins

Command I executed is

export DISPLAY=:0;

Answer (score 1):

You might want to prepare a profile for Selenium in Firefox: see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7154404/1012381) can help (the answer is not marked as *answered* but the OP posted his solution.

Answer (score 1):

In our Jenkins implementation, we use Xvfb as a headless X server for Firefox to run in. You can see details of our implementation here http://www.hiringthing.com/2012/04/13/automated-ui-testing-with-jenkins-selenium.html

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error trying to get selenium to run headless. After some searching I realised that the user I was running selenium as didn't have access to the Firefox profile directory I had created. Changing the permissions on the profile directory got me past this error.